# Why I can't read from and write to socket with printf and scanf?

Tags: c, io, sockets

I wonder why this code is not working. I mean: When both the server and client are running I can type and type with no result. However, when I kill the client, the server starts outputting everything I previously wrote to the client app.

full server.c: https://pastebin.com/iXSYLZS3

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT 8080

int main(void)
{
        // some code to initialize connection

        printf("connection accepted!\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        close(0);
        dup(sock);
        while (1) {
                scanf("%s", str);
                printf("%s", str);
                fflush(stdout);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

full client.c: https://pastebin.com/sFmi72ZP

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
 
#define PORT 8080
 
int main(void)
{
        // some code to initialize connection
 
        printf("connected!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
 
        close(1);
        dup(sock);
        while (1) {
                scanf("%s", str);
                printf("%s", str);
                fflush(stdout);
        }
 
        return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may appear to 'work', but that is just by accident. Closing the underlying descriptor of a `FILE*` and replacing it with another is bound to confuse the FILE implementation at some point (most likely during that important demo)

The safe way is to use `fdopen` to create a new `FILE*` from the given socket and then use `fscanf`/`fprintf` if you insist on using that.

`fdopen` is a posix function, but so is `dup` so I guess you are on a posix system.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I just had to add newline at the end of the string for pipe to be flushed. Eg. I used:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

instead of:

```
printf("%s", str);
```